# Why the client and server certificate for TLS?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tls1.2

What's the purpose of the client and server certificate for setting up TLS on Mariadb/mysql? I would have thought that just a server certificate was enough in the same way a web server like Apache works with the client only needing to trust the certificate the server is presenting?

Comment: Just because for most of the https connections only a server certificate is used, does not mean you can't use client certificates for authenticating the clients. Myswl's use of client certificates is no different in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of client certificates is so the server can validate the client in the same way the client can validate the server.

[CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html#create-user-tls) with `REQUIRE X509` and/or `REQUIRE ISSUER` enforce this as an authentication requirement.

If you want a non-TLS mechanism for authenticating clients, then no client certificate/key is required.

Answer (score 0):

In TLS, you can setup **mutual** authentication which means that the Client will validate server's certificate, and **vice-versa**. This means that Server will also validate the client's certificate. However, **mutual** authentication is not mandatory, and in many cases, only the client validates the server certificate which is one-way authentication. It is entirely up to your purview and design how you want your application/setup to behave, and whether mutual or one-way TLS authentication is enough in your case.

Here is a good reference link:- http://www.ossmentor.com/2015/03/one-way-and-two-way-ssl-and-tls.html